# Using HTTP Client (axios, rm ...) from Vuex 4 store

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex4, typed-rest-client

i've been searching a work around to use any http client on my Vuex mutations/actions

I'm using Vuex4 with Vue3 and Typescript, here's what i've tried so far

`src/plugins/http.ts`

```js
import { Plugin } from 'vue';
import rm from 'typed-rest-client';

const http: Plugin = {
  install(app, options) {
    app.config.globalProperties.$http = rm;

    app.provide('http', options);
  },
};

export default http;
```

`src/main.ts`

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import http from '@/plugins/http';
import App from '@/App';
import store from '@/store';

const app = createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(http)
  .mount('#app');
```

And then tried to access $http from global this in mutations or actions, but looks like there's no way to retrieve Vue instance from the store

Another work around was to add this line on `src/main.ts`

```js
store.$app = app;
```

There Typescript wasn't happy about the Store interface who wasn't prepared to get $app, maybe is there a way to override this type ?

The last one is working but I don't really like the usage. The idea is to add a parameter to your payload who takes the current Vue instance of where the dispatch is called. Looks kinda like this

```js
await this.$store.dispatch(ActionTypes.TEST, { app: this });
```

And then use it in the mutation like this

```js
async [MutationTypes.TEST](state, payload) {
  console.log(payload.app.$http); // Yaaay I get it !
},
```

If you guys are aware of another way to use a global property from the Vuex store I'm all ears !
Thanks for reading, hope someone could help me !

Comment: It shouldn't be used as a global property. Import it. *Typescript wasn't happy about the Store interface who wasn't prepared to get $app,* - then probably it should be prepared. It's not uncommon to store global instances in a store, although this looks like useless abstraction.